# Notification not firing because of differing string formats in a NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray

I am having some weird problem. I send names and dates in a parameter to a notification method.

So when my name array is like this:

```
 name(   
    "John Miller",
    "mahiya",
    "Shane Jarome",
    "Sharon Scott",
    "Sheron Begley",
    "Susan Diaz",
    today 
)
```

It works perfectly. The Notification gets fired, but when my name array is like this

```
name(
    helo,  <--  NO DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK THIS IS THE ONLY DIFFERENCE 
    Johnn,
    "David?",
    Nowww,
    "John Miller",
    "mahiya",
    "Shane Jarome",
    "Sharon Scott",
    "Sheron Begley",
    "Susan Diaz",
    today
)
```

It doesn't work.

Can anybody tell me why is this happening? When I use `NSLog` on the array's specific element it never shows the quotation marks. So how can I make the array show quotation marks when I print the whole array?

Comment: What kind of notification method and how?

Comment: how can i convert this array of string into array of string but all element are in quotation

Comment: you mean like `@"\"text\""` (with quotation) instead of `@"text"`(without)

Comment: i mean convert all string in way like when i print array so it should print "Shane Jarome",
    "Sharon Scott",
    "Sheron Begley",
    "Susan Diaz", all are in qoute

Comment: can you give the code where you generate your array and where you print it?